# How to make a UserControl being wrapped inside a DIV with the generated ClientID

Tags: c#, asp.net, webusercontrol

If I have a `UserControl` like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Foo.ascx.cs" Inherits="Foo" %>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TxtFoo" />
```

And I include it into my page as follows:

```
...
<uc:Foo runat="server" ID="UcFoo" />
...
```

I would like to have my `UserControl` being wrapped inside a `DIV` with the `ClientID` as follows:

```
<div id="ctl00$ContentPH$UcFoo">
  <input type="text" name="ctl00$ContentPH$UcFoo$TxtFoo" id="ctl00$ContentPH$UcFoo$TxtFoo" />
</div>
```

But actually I'm getting *the content without the `DIV` tag*. So the question here is: **How can I tell ASP.NET to render my control inside a DIV with the auto-generated ClientID?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the contents of your UserControl inside a `<div>` with an `id` attribute:

```
<div id="<%= this.ClientID %>">
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TxtFoo" />
</div>
```

Note that the `ClientID` will contain underscores, not dollar signs (as in your example).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will give it a try. As for the note, the separator in `ClientID` is customizable, it can be any character such the dollar sign or underscore, it depends on the configuration of each `UserControl`.

Comment: I didn't know you can customize the separator. How do you do that?

Comment: Sorry @Michael-liu, my mistake, I was mis-reading this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidseparator.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Option 1:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server">
  <asp:TextBox runat="Server" Id="txtFoo" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Option 2:

Write a custom control, override the Render method & write out your own string...

HTH.

Comment: Will it take the `ClientID` from the ASPX page?